# Easiest way to parallelize filter and list operations

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, gpu

My program uses a lot of `filter`, `all` and list comprehensions which I  believe are great candidates for parallelization (either via multithreading or GPU programming).

So what would be the easiest way to parallelize those functions?  I'm looking for a fairly easy to implement method (i.e. need not be the most efficient or achieve the highest level of parallelism) to get an idea of the potential speedup before diving into more complicated methods such as PyCUDA and such.

Comment: I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python) that it can be done relatively easily, but this approach will require me to untangle many of my `filter`s, was just wondering since `filter` almost feels like it's built for parallelism, if there would be an even simpler way

Comment: The second highest answer to that question uses `multiprocessing.map` which seems like the easiest way: http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/

Comment: @Rufus do you still have the code, can you edit and add that to the question? :D